# Appcelerator iOS publishing itunes. Binary uploaded is invalid

Tags: binary, app-store-connect, appcelerator

Good evening,
Following the update of appcelerator I can no longer publish application on itunes connect.

I created a new project
An itunes publishing certificate
And an itunes project

It is impossible to upload it with Xcode or Application Loader each time my binary is invalid.

Do you have the same mistake?

Comment: the error on application loader is 
ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."

Answer (score 0):

What is your Xcode version and Ti SDK version? Try to build your App with the latest version. Make sure your App is running perfectly on the real device. Also, remove the user from the Xcode then add it again. You can check out following doc link

- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Distributing_iOS_apps

Hope this helps.

Comment: Xcode 8.3.2
Ti SDK 6.0.4
Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.8.1.201612050850
was working perfectly since yesterday... :/

Comment: message from Xcode

This action could not be completed. try Again (-22421)